# Calculations over UNION, merge query repetitive code

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am struggling with this query a lot mainly because of the repetition which possibly could be reduced - hopefully.

The general idea is to display sums of each table for a given month and display it as a pivot table.

Current code is in my opinion very messy and repetitive but the main thing is it doesn't allow me to make the calculations, due the UNION joining.

For each month as following ( I assume this has to be a derivative table that takes values of the other and calculates this formula for each month ):

```
Calculation Formula = (
    employees_salaries + 
    employees_salaries_insurence_costs +
    employees_agreement +
    employees_agreement_insurence_cost + 
    employees_extras +
    employees_to_hand +
    employees_delegations ) - employees_deductions
```

Current query is working displays everything properly but the questions and desired output :

- Question : Is there any possible query minification
           - Possible query structure to enable the calculation formula

Desired output : Current layout is what needs to stay

I am trying since few days but I am unable to accomplish my desired result, any tips will be really helpful.

Output

```
+------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
|         employees_salaries         |       January       | Febr | March | April | May | June | July  |  August  | September | October | November | December |
+------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
| employees_salaries                 | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 | 15826.12 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
| Calculations                       | Calculation Formula |      |       |       |     |      |       |          |           |         |          |          |
| employees_salaries_insurence_costs | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |  5044.44 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
| employees_agreement                | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |   250 |        0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |     3550 |
| employees_agreement_insurence_cost | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 | 71.05 |        0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |   178.65 |
| employees_extras                   | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |        0 |         0 |    1.00 |        0 |        0 |
| employees_deductions               | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |    45.60 |         0 |    1.00 |        0 |        0 |
| employees_to_hand                  | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |        0 |         0 |  111.00 |   555.00 |        0 |
| employees_delegations              | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |        0 |      2520 |     540 |        0 |        0 |
+------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

MCVE Example + Schema : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RvfD3uA4cSSVgmhoP2co6/9

Comment: What do your tables look like?

Comment: Check it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RvfD3uA4cSSVgmhoP2co6/9 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment/question about reducing the number of times we query the `employees_salaries` and `employees_agreement` tables ...

We can use a cartesian product (aka cross join) with a 2-row dummy table to unpivot these tables, eg:

```
select case when c.col1 = 'a'
            then 'employees_salaries' 
            else 'employees_salaraies_insurence_cost'
       end                                             as ctype,
       mmonth                                          as cdate,
       case when c.col1 = 'a'
            then gross
            else insurence_cost1+insurence_cost2
       end                                             as camount

from   employees_salaries

cross
join   (select 'a' as col1
        union all
        select 'b') c

where  year(mmonth) = year(curdate())

ctype                               cdate       camount
----------------------------------  ----------  -------
employees_salaries                  2017-08-01  1000
employees_salaraies_insurence_cost  2017-08-01  308.7
employees_salaries                  2017-08-01  2000
employees_salaraies_insurence_cost  2017-08-01  666.4
....
```

We then place these 'unpivot' queries into our previous derived table.

---

Regarding the requirement to generate the `Calculations` record (sum up each month per the given `Calculations` equation), first some assumptions:

- all numeric values are positive (this includes `deductions`)
- per OP's comment, target db is Maria 10.1, which does not have support for cte's

To calculate our totals we'll use a set of 12 variables (@s1 - @s12) to keep a running tally of monthly values, along with a tweak to keep from displaying a separate column for our variables ...

Sample data:

```
create table t1(a int);
insert into t1 values (1),(2),(3);
```

First pass at using `@s` to keep a running sum:

```
select 'raw',a,@s:=@s+a
from   t1

cross
join   (select @s:=0) v;    /* initialize our variable */

      a   @s:=@s+a
----  --  --------
raw   1   1
raw   2   3
raw   3   6
```

Notice how our variable assignment shows up as a 3rd column, with the displayed value being the 'new' value of the variable.

We can eliminate this 3rd column and still perform our calculations by a) multiplying the **result** of the variable assignment by zero(0) and b) adding this zero'd result to another number (eg, our `a` column in this case), eg:

```
select 'raw',a + (0* @s:=@s+a) as 'a'
from   t1

cross
join   (select @s:=0) v;

      a 
----  -- 
raw   1 
raw   2 
raw   3
```

Lastly, we can use a `union all` to display our final sum, like such:

```
select 'raw',a + (0* @s:=@s+a) as 'a'
from   t1

cross
join   (select @s:=0) v

union all

select 'sum',@s;

      a 
----  -- 
raw   1 
raw   2 
raw   3
sum   6      <=== @s
```

---

For the actual calculations ... we want to **add** all numbers, except for the `deductions` value.  While we could add a bunch of `case` expressions to determine when to **add** vs **subtract** a value, instead we'll:

- automatically negate all `deductions` values as we pull them from the base table
- for display purposes we'll apply `abs(..value..)`; this will allow us to display the `deductions` row as positive values
- and for our variable assignments we simply add the current `camount` as is (it'll be positive for most columns, negative for `deductions`)

When we tie the `abs()` and zero'd-out variable assignments together we get something like this:

```
select ctype as employees_salaries,

       /* need to make sure the variable assignments take place inside
          the `sum()` constructs for the `group by` to function properly.
       */

       COALESCE(SUM(case when month(cdate)=1  then abs(camount) + (0*@s1:=@s1  +camount) end),0) As January, 
       COALESCE(SUM(case when month(cdate)=2  then abs(camount) + (0*@s2:=@s2  +camount) end),0) As Febr, 
       ....
from
( /* dual-unpivot, multi-union query of the source tables */ )

cross  /* initialize our variables */
join   (select @s1:=0, @s2:=0, @s3:=0, @s4:=0,  @s5:=0,  @s6:=0,
               @s7:=0, @s8:=0, @s9:=0, @s10:=0, @s11:=0, @s12:=0) v

group by ctype, year(cdate)

union all

/* display our monthly totals
*/
select  'Calculations',
        @s1, @s2, @s3, @s4,  @s5,  @s6,
        @s7, @s8, @s9, @s10, @s11, @s12
```

And last but not least, we'll add a bit of a convoluted `order by` clause to ensure our `Calculations` row shows up last, while ordering the other records by their ctype/name; for all source records we'll generate a zero(0), and for the `Calculations` row we'll generate a one(1); we then sort by this generated number and the ctype/name value:

```
order by case when employees_salaries != 'Calculations' then 0 else 1 end, employees_salaries
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RvfD3uA4cSSVgmhoP2co6/17) for this unpivot + @variables solution.

NOTE: Some of the sums are showing more than 2 decimal places of accuracy ... not sure what the issue is there ... should be easy enough to reformat the data as needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69939/discussion-on-answer-by-markp-calculations-over-union-merge-query-repetitive-co).

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the odd ball row (Calculations/Calculation Formula) for the moment, I opted for doing a `union all` of the raw data (in a derived table), and then grouped/pivoted the derived table, eg:

```
select ctype                                                       As employees_salaries,
       COALESCE(SUM(case when month(cdate)=1  then camount end),0) As January, 
       COALESCE(SUM(case when month(cdate)=2  then camount end),0) As Febr, 
       COALESCE(SUM(case when month(cdate)=3  then camount end),0) As March, 
       ...
from   (select 'employees_salaries'                  as ctype,
               mmonth                                as cdate,
               gross                                 as camount
        from   employees_salaries
        where  year(mmonth) = year(curdate())

        union all

        select 'employees_salaries_insurence_costs',
               mmonth,
               insurence_cost1+insurence_cost2
        from   employees_salaries
        where  year(mmonth) = year(curdate())

        union all
        ... ) as c
group by ctype, year(cdate)

order by 1
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RvfD3uA4cSSVgmhoP2co6/10) for the complete query.